# Playing audio file using itunes SDK

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, itunes

I am developing a windows form C# application that should be able to interface with iTunes. Basically, I now am able to use the iTunes COM to play music. However, when I do this, iTunes should be running since the music plays through iTunes. I was wondering if there is a way I can play music without iTunes running. Is it possible to just use the iTunes SDK to play music without starting iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. iTunesLib COM Object is just a way to control the player engine implemented in the iTunes application, and to manage the media library.

Even if you would like to implement your own player, you couldn't avoid iTunes showing up, because it's showing up when iTunes object is instanciated.

The only way is to implement your own (background) player and to parse the iTunes media library file with some XML process.

Comment: That's what i thought. Why would apple let you use their dll with no string attached?